# Regex match directories and then match subdirectories

Tags: python, regex

For example, if I have a list of paths (ie. dir1/subdirA, dir2/subdirB, dir1/subdirB, etc..). I have a regex to match some directory names and then another regex to match the subdirectories. What's the best way to get the valid paths. Or is there a way to combine the two regex using the 2 existing regex?

```
DIR_RE = re.compile(r'somedirname', re.I)

SUB_RE = re.compile(r'^/somesubdir$', re.I)
```

Comment: You will need to provide the regular expressions you are using and some sample data you expect to match/discard. As is this question is very broad.

Comment: simply concatenate them `'somedirname\/somesubdir'`, And then apply this regex over the whole list to directory paths.

Comment: in common case you should prefer [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html). But you should provide more details.

Comment: Would the valid directories necessarily follow the "dirX/subdirY" pattern in your case? Or is it just an example?

Comment: @SebasSBM It is just an example.

Comment: Please improve your question, so people have actually chance to answer. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your regexen don't seem to match any of the sample paths you've provided in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

directories = ["dir1/subdirA", "dir2/subdirB", "dir1/subdirB", "subdir9/dirC"]

expression = re.compile('^dir[1-9]\/subdir[A-Z]$', re.I)

for directory in directories:
    if (re.match(expression, directory)):
        print "Yes the directory path :" +directory+ "  is valid"
        #Do something.
        #Passed cases = ["dir1/subdirA", "dir2/subdirB", "dir1/subdirB"]
    else:
        #Failed cases = ["subdir9/dirC"]
        #Do something here.
```

**NOTE :** The regex is created keeping in mind the example provided in case your directory structure is different, you have to change it accordingly.

Comment: This is very helpful, but not quite what I'm looking for. If I have DIR_RE = re.compile(r'dir[1-9]', re.I) and SUB_RE = re.compile(r'subdir[A-Z]', re.I), is there anyway to combine the two existing regex?

Comment: I am used to use re.compile() often, but I didn't know it accepted a second arg. What is it for?

Comment: I see. For case insensitive regexp. I saw it here https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile

Comment: @user2378481 I don't think there is any way of combining two regex expressions directly, But I am not sure if some indirect method does exists.

Comment: Please check out my answer below. It's more or less like combining two or more regexps in one (some kind of indirect method, but very good)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both regexps this way. This example is an alternative based on solution proposed by @ZdaR.

```
import re
directories = ["dir1/subdirA", "dir2/subdirB", "dir1/subdirB", "subdir9/dirC"]

regexp = re.compile('^(dir[1-9])\/(subdir[A-Z])$', re.I)

for path in directories:
    frag = regexp.match(path)
    if frag != None:
        dir_str = frag.group(1)
        subdir_str = frag.group(2)
        entire_match = frag.group(0)
        # Do something with them
```

Notice the parenthesis in the regexp. These parenthesis allow to define several groups inside the regexp, so fragments of every match can be obtained using group(n) method over the Match object.

This regexp assumes that the length of every path will be only 2

(Eg: 'dir/subdir' and not 'dir/subdir/subdir')

I hope this will help.